# How to push local changes to a contributor's fork of the repo?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

With github, I've got a contributor who opened a PR. I cloned their branch, and have now made my own changes on top of their original changes.

I want to push my local changes to his branch, so that they appear on the PR. I can do this via the github UI by clicking "edit file", but I can't figure out how to do this without them giving me push access to their fork?

Comment: Submit a pull request to *their* repository and have them merge your changes?

Comment: That seems awefully indirect ): So there's no way to force push my changes onto their PR? (even though the base repository is my own)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add their remote first so you can checkout and commit to the branch. However, they **must** have checked the "Allow edits by maintainers" option when creating the PR (it's checked by default).

After adding the remote, just checkout the branch using the newer `switch` command. It should automatically know that the branch is on the upstream/fork remote.

```bash
$ git remote add FORK_NAME FORK_URI
$ git switch FORK_BRANCH
```

You can read more detailed instructions here [on the GitHub Docs page](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/committing-changes-to-a-pull-request-branch-created-from-a-fork).